# how to have a selector in a custom view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would think this is possible but due to common words am unable to google whether this is possible and, if yes,  what I'm doing wrong. I need to have a button in a custom view with drawrect and have it respond to a selector

```
   // in drawrect

    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ....

}

-(void)buttonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"you clicked the button");
}
```

and when running get an unrecgonized selector error:

```
2013-11-21 20:06:24.847 customui[8529:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[IAMax buttonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ca7d00'
```

Is this possible? What am I doing wroing? thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action selector and the actual method are not the same. One is `buttonClicked:` and the other is `buttonClicked`.

Change the selector to match the actual method.

```
@selector(buttonClicked)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In your  code     `@selector(buttonClicked:)` you added that you are calling method with argument so your selector method must be  written as follows:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"you clicked the button");
}
```

Comment: thx for explanation, knew that colon existed there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove:

Because if you add:

You should add id sender into method name

Comment: @BryanChen It's a valid, though somewhat cryptic, answer.